# will not boot second time round

Tags: boot

I'm getting a bit stressed out with this (trying to log in to Ubuntu) The install from live USB on to my windows XP system went well, gave the Ubuntu op system 25gig and it installed. 
I'm running a AMD athlon II 4core CPU, 4gig DDR3 800mhz memory, 500gig HDD, Gforce xfx 8600 graphics card.
I booted back up today and  its telling me I've got serious errors on my disk at /
I've gone into the grub menu tried (nomodeset) also tried running recovery mode and check for bad packages ect, all I keep getting is a screen with documentation informing me Linux is free software and comes with no warranty.
It also keeps telling "locked read only file system" I've tried the change rw to ro command and god knows how many others!
I've forgotten half the things I've tried tonight. I'm new to Linux wanted to get in to this and experience all the positive things I've been reading, but at the moment I'm just pulling out my hair.
Any advice would be a big help
Cheers
Noel

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to re-install, but if that's what it takes I'll give it ago. Thanks for the advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the assumption that you are partitioning your HDD via linux live so what I would recommend is creating an unformatted partition through windows and try the installation process all over again selecting the unformatted partition as your allocated drive space for linux.

I'm not sure why Ubuntu has trouble with partitioning drives through the liveCD but every time that I've installed Ubuntu I encounter some sort of problem when doing it that route. So I go the windows route and up until now I have had problem-free installations.